# How to Fix -Unity 2020.3.30.f1 + MRTK + openXR = Error: CS0108: 'HololensHand.trackingState' hides inherited member 'TrackedDevice.trackingState'

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, openxr

I am running Unity 2020.3.30.f1 + MRTK Example project, when I follow prompts to import OpenXR plugin for Microsoft Hololens feature group I receive this error:

.cs(82,31): error CS0108: 'HololensHand.trackingState' hides inherited member 'TrackedDevice.trackingState'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

as well as a number of other CS0108 errors on other MRTK scripts.

Any advice on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify the MRTK Example project you mentioned? Is that [MRTK Examples Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/example-scenes/example-hub?view=mrtkunity-2021-05) or [Example scenes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/running-example-scenes?view=mrtkunity-2021-05) provided by MRTK?

Comment: Have you Installed [Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/xr-project-setup?tabs=openxr#manual-setup-without-mrtk) with the new Mixed Reality Feature Tool application for your project? Generally wondering the detailed steps to reproduce your issue.